# SQLITE loosening or eliminating enum constraint

Tags: sqlite

Am reading that altering table constraints for SQLITE is limited, but hoping there is a way I missed to either add a new choice to an enumerated type of constraint, or to drop the constraint altogether.

For example say I wanted to add a "GOLDFISH" to a Pet table created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Pet" (
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    species VARCHAR,
    CHECK (species IN ('DOG', "CAT")),
)
```

Is there a way I can alter the table to make it legal to do so short of creating a new table and transfering the data?

Comment: Sadly in my case the enum type constraint is already in place on multiple customer databases. My intent is to just drop the constraint, since the db is maintained by code that enforces the same restriction in its representation of the table rows anyway. But if I were starting a new db where I needed the constraint and the db was not managed by code I could control, I would favor such an approach.